# arraylist value into string value

Tags: java

I have a arraylist containing values like [ addidas 5 100 , nike 10 300 , woodland 4 800] so if i print am gettinh result as

```
value1 :: adidas
value2 :: 5
value3 :: 100
```

result has to be like

```
value1 :: adidas,nike,woodland
value2 :: 5,10,4
value3 :: 100,300,800
```

```
ArrayList<String> array;

int j = 0;

String[] parts;
String value1;
String value2;
String value3;

for (j = 0; j <= array.size(); j++) {

    parts = array.split(" ");

    value1 = parts[0];
    value2 = parts[1];
    value3 = parts[2];

    System.out.println("value1::" + value1);
    System.out.println("value2::" + value2);
    System.out.println("value3::" + value3);

}
```

Comment: parse the array into Value objects.

Comment: `parts = array.split(" ");` what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I think he/she means `array.get(j).split(" ");`

Comment: Where is the code where you're actually putting stuff into the array?

Comment: I know @DavidWallace that is what I wanted to get from him/her

Comment: I wonder why so many people tend to ask questions that will most likely make the original poster ask questions back. Couldn't someone tell the OP that `array` is empty, which is why stuff most likely wont happen?

Comment: Well, if he/she presents some results and some pretended results, he/she in someway fills the array, becouse he/she shows some results obtained.

Comment: @Izmaki I assume that OP filled his list earlier and didn't include it in his code example to make it shorter.

Comment: @Pshemo yes to make it shorter i did not show

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Since this looks like homework there will be no code here.</sub>
There is one error in your code and few in logic.

- `split` can be invoked on `String` so first you should `get` that string from your array list
- you said that you want to print all elements of the same category (value1, value2, value3) in same line but your loop prints one value of each category in each iteration. To solve this problem you should store split values in separated lists and print them after loop ends.